# Total defect of each release using Talend Big Data

Tags: talend, rest-client

I'm using Talend OS for Big Data for data pull from ALM and it is working fine. Already i have total result of defect. Now, i need to take the total defect count of each release OR sprint.

How can i get total defect count of each release OR sprint using Talend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use taggregaterow component in TOS for BD. 
Group by - release OR sprint 
Operations- Count on defects

For more information on taggregaterow you can go to link- https://help.talend.com/reader/jomWd_GKqAmTZviwG_oxHQ/yj8JuBj57qWaYoFqIewUiA